# MVC IEnumable toList return no result when I have 2 where()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable

When I have 1 filter, my code works fine but when I have 2 filters, the ToList() return no rows. I tried the run the SQL that the code generates and SQL did return something.

```
IEnumerable<Tag> tags = db.Tags;

if( ID != "")
    tags = tags.Where(t => t.ID == ID);

if( part != "")
    tags = tags.Where(t => t.PartNumber == part);

tags.OrderBy(t => t.ID);
tags = tags.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize);

return View(tags.ToList());
```

when both filter exists, 0 rows will return.

Output SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (10)
  [Project1].[ID] AS [ID],
  [Project1].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber]
FROM (SELECT
  [Project1].[ID] AS [ID],
  [Project1].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] DESC) AS [row_number]
FROM (SELECT
  [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
  [Extent1].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber]
FROM [Tag] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0)
AND ([Extent1].[PartNumber] = @p__linq__1)) AS [Project1]) AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] DESC
```

Comment: What is your sample data, what is the value of `ID`, what is the value of `part` and what is the value of `PageIndex`?

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with your code.

Comment: ID & part are just string, ID = "123", part = "A001", PageIndex is int which is 0 in this case.

Comment: Please show the SQL that the code generates that returns something!

Comment: Per your update: If you run that SQL in server management studio but fill in the two parameters do you get rows?

Comment: I do, how to check the value of @p__linq__0 and @p__linq__1?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've already filtered your list.

When this is executed:

```
tags = tags.Where(t => t.ID == ID);
```

Your tags collection has been updated and now contains a list based on the filter.

When you subsequently do this:

```
tags = tags.Where(t => t.PartNumber == part);
```

Unless you have a tag that has the given ID and PartNumber, nothing will be returned.

If you want to build up a conditional filter, you can do something like this:

```
var query = tags.AsQueryable();

if(ID != "")
    query = query.Where(w => w.ID == ID);

// add second filter
if( part != "")
    query = query.Where(w => w.PartNumber == part);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: I am pretty sure both ID & part exist in the same record, in fact if I search them separately, they work (shows same record).

Comment: Can you post the output of the content of your list?  See update that may help.

Comment: It's increasingly looking like the fact that no data is coming back is because you have no single records that match BOTH criteria.  Again, can you please post the data that is in the table (or better, what is in your `IEnumerable<Tag>` variable.

Comment: Also, are you using a case insensitive or case sensitive collation on your database?

Comment: Brendan, I am pretty sure that both values exists in the same record. And I am sure the input case matches with the record in DB.

Comment: Then that query should work.  So, maybe there's something that you're missing that another set of eyes could pick up, which is why I'm asking to see the data that you have in your table.